# What is an ON-unit?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, language-agnostic, white-box-testing

[The Art of Software Testing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118031962) contains several references to "*ON*-units". Here is an example from the section on test-case design:

> Decision coverage usually can satisfy statement coverage. Since every statement is on some subpath emanating either from a branch statement or from the entry point of the program, every statement must be executed if every branch direction is executed. There are, however, at least three exceptions:
>
> - Programs with no decisions.
> - Programs or subroutines/methods with multiple entry points. A given statement might be executed only if the program is entered at a particular entry point.
> - Statements within *ON*-units. Traversing every branch direction will not necessarily cause all *ON*-units to be executed.

I haven't seen the term *ON*-unit before, and I'm having trouble finding a definition on google. What is an *ON*-unit?

Comment: This book is used for Software QA in WGU's Software development program. So glad you asked this question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An *ON-unit* is a method of exception handling in the [PL/I language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/I#On-Units_and_exception_handling), like a `catch` block in more modern languages. So it sounds as if they're saying that executing every branch of code (outside the ON-units) won't necessarily trigger all the handled exceptions (inside the ON-units).